# Solving a maze by using right hand rule

Tags: c#, maze

I'm trying to solve the maze by using the right hand rule, but my backtracking is not working correctly. The logical is wrong somehow, if `yPost` is increased, it does not follow the right hand rule. Would anyone tell me what is wrong with my function ? Thank you. This is what I have for my maze:

```
public char[,] navigateMouse()
{
     // check south
     if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == ' ')
     {
          // keep track of the trail
          // by marking it with '.'
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
          mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] = 'M';
          yPos++;
     }
     // check east
     else if (mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] == ' ')
     {
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] = 'M';
          xPos++;
     }
     else if (mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] == ' ')
     {
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
          mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] = 'M';
          yPos--;
     }
     else if (mouseMaze[yPos, xPos - 1] == ' ')
     {
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos] = '.';
          mouseMaze[yPos, xPos - 1] = 'M';
          xPos--;
     }
     // backtrack
     else
     {
          if (mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] == '.')
          {
               mouseMaze[yPos + 1, xPos] = 'M';
               yPos++;
          }
          else if (mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] == '.')
          {
               mouseMaze[yPos, xPos + 1] = 'M';
               xPos++;
          }
          else if (mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] == '.')
          {
               mouseMaze[yPos - 1, xPos] = 'M';
               yPos--;
          }
          else if (mouseMaze[yPos, xPos - 1] == '.')
          {
               mouseMaze[yPos, xPos - 1] = 'M';
               xPos--;
          }
     }

     if (mouseMaze[mazeHeight/2, mazeWidth - 1] == 'M')
          gameWon = true;

     return mouseMaze;
}
```

Comment: Can you, just for reference, post a sample maze content? `.` are for the trail, spaces for the empty area. What else is there?

Comment: @Shaamaan: The maze is filled with character 'X' and whitespace in which 'X' means wall/obstacles and whitespace mean you are free to traverse to. The '.' is used to keep track of the path that I've been traversed to. For example, move from A to B, I will mark A with '.' and B will now be marked 'M'.

Comment: I think you need to mark the location you were in with '.' before you backtrack, so you don't get stuck there in a loop

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is actually following the 'right hand rule' since 'right hand' is relative and you aren't taking into account 'M's direction.

Comment: @DFreeman: so how am I gonna apply the right hand rule on the maze if it is relative ?

Comment: @HoangMinh You should store the previous location you came from, that way you know which direction is now your "forward" and which direction is therefore "right". BTW you should heed my answer, as I suspect your code leads to endless loops.

Comment: @Hoang Minh: You'd need to track Ms direction as well as position then change the order that you check the tiles to check the right first, if it's blocked then turn left and repeat. Infact, this method means that whether M has visited a tile before or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the line mouseMaze[ypos, xpos] = '.' at the start of your navigate function, to mark where you currently are. When you backtrack you haven't marked where you were and you just keep going to that location over and over